# GraphQLParser nesting limitation

Tags: c++, facebook, graphql, crash, stack-overflow

I'm using Facebook's C++ library `GraphQLParser` to parse GraphQL queries.

If I pass the library a query with an extremely large number of nested selection sets - it crashes due to stack overflow.

Query for example:

```
query X {
  name {
    name {
      name {
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to configure the library to impose a restriction on the depth of nested selection sets?

Thanks

Comment: You should file a bug for that. GraphQL queries tend to be sent by end users and the library should handle too deep nesting gracefully.